# how to set up dirContextValidator?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, ldap, spring-ldap

https://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/1.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/pooling.html

```
open fun create(): LdapTemplate {
        return LdapTemplate(PooledContextSource(
            PoolConfig().apply {
                maxTotalPerKey = 10
                isTestOnBorrow = true
                isTestWhileIdle = true
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = timeToMillis
            })
            .apply {
                contextSource = ldapContextSourceFactory.create()
            })
            .apply {
                setIgnorePartialResultException(true)
                afterPropertiesSet()
            }
    }
```

if add this

```
isTestOnBorrow = true
isTestWhileIdle = true
```

doesn’t work

```
Failed to borrow DirContext from pool.; nested exception is java.util.NoSuchElementException: Unable to validate object
```

how to set up dirContextValidator ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post a stack trace of the thrown Exception.

Answer (score 0):

Check once your property name is the same or not as mentioned here.  `isTestOnBorrow = true`

```
<property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
<property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
```